# C# Negative IP Address to dotted decimal using intel standards conversion

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to have some help on this since I've been spending hours to do it, but I couldn't. I want to write a function that takes signed integer and convert it to a dotted IP address using Intel standard algorithm, here is an example:

the IP address 192.168.18.188 displays as -1139627840. To convert this IP address using Intel standards, I will have to perform the following procedure:

1. Convert  (-1139627840) to a hex value. BC12A8C0.
2. Reverse the hex bytes, as shown below: CO A8 12 BC
3. Convert the bytes from hex to decimal, as shown below: 192 168 18 188
4. The IP address displays in the following format: 192.168.18.188

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It almost looks like you already know how to do it.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What is this "Intel standard" that you are referring to? Intel is a huge company and I don't really feel like scouring their entire web site to search which one you might mean.

Comment: I am reading values from informix Database, the application that store these values in a Database stores the IP address of the devices as a signed integer value ,what I was trying to do is convert this Int back to an IP but following the same algorithm that application used to store it  and vice versa.the mentioned algorithm is used by intel & informix & Cisco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question in regards to the Intel Standard, but just to throw it out there (in case you're trying to reinvent the wheel), you can convert an int to an IP like this:

```
string ip = new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(-1139627840)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic is in combining:

- the `>>` operator, which shifts the bits in a number to the right
- the `&` operator, which does a bit-wise and (the more common `&&` does a logical and)

So something like this:

```cs
var number = -1139627840;
var b1 = number & 255;
var b2 = (number >> 8) & 255;
var b3 = (number >> 16) & 255;
var b4 = (number >> 24) & 255;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", b1, b2, b3, b4));
```